# Listview search with custom adapter not showing search results properly

Tags: android, listview, filter

Searching in Listview are not working properly. If i enter string that is in my array list it shows all the records but if i enter any other string in my edit text field it shows an empty list.

```
public class GetCustomList extends ListActivity {

TweetListAdaptor myAdaptor;
ListView lv;
EditText searchTxt;
public ArrayList<Contact> tweets = new ArrayList<Contact>();


DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_info);
    tweets = db.getAllContacts();


     lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


     searchTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearchNameField);  
     searchTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myAdaptor.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            onPostExecute(null);

        }
    });


    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts

    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 
     db.addContact(new Contact("786","zahid", "bilaltown", '0'));
     db.addContact(new Contact("123","Shahid", "bilaltown", '0'));
     db.addContact(new Contact("123","waqas", "bilaltown", '0'));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 

    for (Contact cn : tweets) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.get_id()+ ",Code:"+ cn.get_code() +" ,Name: " + cn.get_name() + " ,Address: " + cn.get_address() + " ,Phone: " + cn.get_limit();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);
}


}

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        myAdaptor = new TweetListAdaptor(GetCustomList.this, tweets);
        myAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(myAdaptor);

    }


    public class TweetListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> implements Filterable {

        private ArrayList<Contact> mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Contact>(); // Original Values
        private ArrayList<Contact> mDisplayedValues = new ArrayList<Contact>();    // Values to be displayed
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;

        public TweetListAdaptor(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> items) {
                  super(context, R.layout.custom_list_info, items);
                  this.mOriginalValues = items;
                  this.mDisplayedValues = items;
                  this.context = context;
                 // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDisplayedValues.size();
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


       public class ViewHolder {
            private TextView CustomerId;
            private TextView CustomerShop;
            private TextView date;
            private TextView phoneNumber;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                 this.CustomerId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomerID);
                 this.CustomerShop = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);

                // this.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
                // this.status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.staus);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_info, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
                        v.setTag(holder);
                }else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    }

                final Contact o = getItem(position);
                if (o != null) {

                    holder.CustomerId.setText(""+o._id);
                    holder.CustomerShop.setText(o._name);

                    //holder.date.setText(o.date);
                    //holder.status.setText(o.status_txt);
                    /*if(o.status.equals("1")){
                         RelativeLayout llr = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.testRes);
                         llr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.decline);
                    }else if(o.status.equals("2")){
                         RelativeLayout llr = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.testRes);
                         llr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.acceptence);
                        }
                }*/

                ImageButton btnSearchCustomer = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchCustomer);
                btnSearchCustomer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(GetCustomList.this, CustomerDetailedInfo.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ccode", o._code);
                        intent.putExtra("cname", o._name);
                        intent.putExtra("caddress", o._address);
                        intent.putExtra("climit", o._limit);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });     
           }
                return v;      
        }

      ///////////////////////////////

      @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                mDisplayedValues = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                ArrayList<Contact> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Contact>(mDisplayedValues); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                /********
                 * 
                 *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                 *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                 *
                 ********/
              if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return  
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i)._name;
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(new Contact(mOriginalValues.get(i)._name,mOriginalValues.get(i)._code,mOriginalValues.get(i)._address,mOriginalValues.get(i)._limit));
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    } 

      ///////////////////

    }
```

Contact class

```
public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _code;
String _name;
String _address;
int _limit;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String _code,String name,String address, int _limit){
    this._id = id;
    this._code = _code;
    this._name = name;
    this._address = address;
    this._limit = _limit;

}

// constructor
public Contact(String _code,String name, String address,int _limit){
    this._code = _code;
    this._name = name;
    this._address = address;
    this._limit = _limit;
}
public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}
public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}
public String get_code() {
    return _code;
}
public void set_code(String _code) {
    this._code = _code;
}
public String get_name() {
    return _name;
}
public void set_name(String _name) {
    this._name = _name;
}
public String get_address() {
    return _address;
}
public void set_address(String _address) {
    this._address = _address;
}
public int get_limit() {
    return _limit;
}
public void set_limit(int _limit) {
    this._limit = _limit;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want it to show?

Comment: How do you mean? You haven't told us anything about the data, or how you want it to match the constraint. As you have it now, it's only returning items that begin with the String entered in the EditText. If you just want it to match any item that contains that String, change `startsWith()` to `contains()`.

Comment: @MikeM. i have shared the complete class code now. I want to make my list searchable by name. What exactly i want to show is that if user enter for example S in edit text field list should show all the names tat start with S.

Comment: And what does it show now? I thought that's what you were saying it did already in your description.

Comment: @MikeM. yes it is showing the data in listview. Now the problem which i,m getting is that suppose i have add three records [mike, waqas, ana] when i enter string in edit text field like "mike" it shows all the records but if i enter "mk" it shows nothing. I don,t know either you are getting me or not. can you please send me your email address i will send you the snapshots about the problem which i,m facing

Comment: Ok, so if you enter "mike" you want it to show _just_ "mike". And if you enter "mk", what do you want it to show? I would think nothing, right?

Comment: @MikeM. Exactly ..... that's what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of minor mistakes in the code. First, you need to override the `getItem()` method in `TweetListAdaptor`:

```
@Override
public Contact getItem(int position)
{
    return mDisplayedValues.get(position);
}
```

Then, in the `Filter`'s `performFiltering()` method, the `code` and `name` parameters are switched for the `Contact` constructor in the following line:

```
FilteredArrList.add(new Contact(mOriginalValues.get(i)._code, mOriginalValues.get(i)._name, mOriginalValues.get(i)._address, mOriginalValues.get(i)._limit));
```

I ran a test with 20 names, and I believe that those corrections should fix the problem.

Comment: It's working now ... Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistakes and helping me out :) So kind of you

Comment: Thanks again ...... Mike i have another issue can you please advise me about it that as well. I want to print invoices through my android app using normal printer or any other. How can i do this??

Comment: I have no clue. I haven't done anything with printing from Android yet. Sorry.

Comment: No problem my friend .... you already have helped me out and i really appreciate it. :)